# Running a php file from init

Tags: linux, php, sysvinit, php5

I am trying to run a php script from init.d in centos 6.9,  when I exit the terminal from which I started the service the application stops, and always the status of the application shows as stopped, even though it is running.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #
    # arrbot        This shell script takes care of starting and stopping
    #               the arbbot
    #
    # chkconfig: - 65 20
    # description:  arbbot trader.
    # processname: arbbot
    # Required-Start: $network $syslog $mysqld
    # Required-Stop:  $network $syslog $mysqld
    # Short-Description: start and stop arbbot server
    # Description: arbbot trader
    ### END INIT INFO

    # Source function library.
    . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

    NAME=arbbot
    DESC="arbbot trader"
    LOGFILE="/var/log/${NAME}.log"
    DAEMON="/usr/bin/php5"
    WORK_DIRECTORY="/var/www/arbbot/"
    DAEMON_OPTS="/var/www/arbbot/main.php"
    ARBDIR="/var/www/arbbot"
    ARBBOT="exec ${DAEMON} ${DAEMON_OPTS} > ${LOGFILE} 2>&1 > NULL"
    LOCK="/var/lock/subsys/arbbot"

    start() {
            echo -n "Starting ${DESC}: "
            cd "${WORK_DIRECTORY}"
            $ARBBOT
            RETVAL=$?
            [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch -- "$LOCK"
            return $RETVAL
    }

    stop() {
            echo -n "Shutting down arbbot: "
            killproc $ARBBOT
            rm -f $LOCK
            return
    }

    restart() {
            stop
            start
    }

    reload() {
            restart
    }

    case "$1" in
    start)
            start
            echo "$NAME."
            ;;
    stop)
            stop
            echo "$NAME."
            ;;
    status)
            status ARBBOT
            RETVAL=$?
            ;;
    restart)
            restart
            ;;
    reload)
            reload
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Usage:  {start|stop|status|reload|restart[|probe]"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac

    exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: It starts a application and keeps on running, like a server. "does it take an infinitely long time to run? " Yes it keeps on running printing messages to the console.

Comment: yes, it does run like that. But the result is not different.

Comment: Try to use 'nohup' as I suggest. It's protect your script from stopping signals after hangup happened (logout from terminal).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to read [Run php script as daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2036746/4688800)
.

Also, more detailed description about writing php daemon like original system daemons - [How to write a PHP Daemon](https://www.xarg.org/2016/07/how-to-write-a-php-daemon/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of features of daemon which do not apply to other process. It needs to close its stdout and stdin, and it needs to dissociate from the controlling process, and its needs to have its cwd set to root ([amongst other things](http://enderunix.org/docs/eng/daemon.php)). There are minimal daemons which can act as a controlling process for running normal processes [as if they were daemons](http://ae.koroglu.org/alternative-way-to-daemonize-java-applications-on-red-hat-centos-linux/) - e.g. [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/)

You also may need custom signal handling and (if you want any dianostic/audit capability) logging capability.

However with the POSIX extensions, all the required functions are exposed - so you can [setsid() and fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613104/why-fork-before-setsid) from within your own code - or even just download [some pre-cooked php code](https://github.com/shamanis/daemon-php/blob/master/daemon.php) to do all this for you.

BEWARE: there are a lot of people publishing code and advice on the internet which is wrong - but they found it worked for them - the code I've linked above is one of the better implementations.

Comment: … including advice like this answer about what dæmons need to do, [which was first noted as wrong advice by IBM in 1995](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html).  Ali Erdinç Köroglu that you hyperlink to has [a mention in the systemd House of Horror](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/daemonize.html).  The idea that one can "daemonize" from an interactive login session to a context outwith it [grew to be a fallacy after the 1980s](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/bsd-service-command.html#Inheritance).

Comment: If the right answer is systemd then we're all in trouble.